# How to Disable SSLv2Hello in JDK1.8u181

Tags: java, security, ssl, java-8

SSLv2Hello cannot be disabled in JDK1.8u181. In the *JDK>/jre/lib/secrity/java.security file, set the "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" as below, but it still doesn't work. I have tried a lower version like JDK1.8u40 and it works as expected(I can disable SSLV2Hello format). I was wondering if there is anything I need to do to get it to work (disable SSLv2Hello).

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, SSLv2Hello, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, 
    EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40

Sample client:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;


public class TLStest2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SSLSocket socket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            
            SSLSocketFactory factory =
                    (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
          socket =  (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("google.com", 443);

          socket.setEnabledProtocols(socket.getSupportedProtocols());
         
          String[] protocols2 = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
          int loop = 1;
          while (loop > 0) {
              System.out.println("Supported Protocols: " + protocols2.length);
              for(int i = 0; i < protocols2.length; i++) {
                  System.out.println(" " + protocols2[i]);
              }
              loop = loop - 1;
              Thread.sleep(10);
          }
          //socket.setEnabledProtocols (protocols);
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            
            socket.startHandshake();

            out = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    socket.getOutputStream())));

            out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
            out.println();
            out.flush();

            if (out.checkError())
                System.out.println("SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

            /* read response */
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null)
                socket.close();
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
    }

}
```

output:
D:\JAVA_WORKSPACE2\TLStest2\src>java TLStest2
Supported Protocols: 5
 SSLv2Hello
 SSLv3
 TLSv1
 TLSv1.1
 TLSv1.2
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
....

According to the network analyzer, the client is still using the old SSL hello format (sslv2hello) for handshaking.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhcx2.png)

Is there any way to disable SSLv2Hello in JDK1.8u181 and later? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Look here for available switches https://java.com/en/configure_crypto.html .

Comment: Thanks, Peter.
I already tried with "‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols" but no luck.
java ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" Tlstest2

Comment: SSLSocket/SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols() works.
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});

 But the product what I am working on is a legacy one and it's supporting "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2". So, looking for alternative options.